# O que significa esse reticências no array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Eu vi que o ES6 tende a ser mais limpo, porém eu não consigo entender algumas coisas:

**1. O que é exatamente esse reticências está fazendo, em teoria?**

```
function getHiddenHTML(el) {
  return [...el.childNodes].reduce((txt, node) => {
     //results
});
```

Eu sei que seria algo assim no ES5, para funcionar, que me deixou mais confuso ainda, o que exatamente estas funções estão fazendo, gostaria de uma explicação teórica sobre isso, valeu:

```
function _toArray(arr) { return _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) || _iterableToArray(arr) || _nonIterableSpread(); }

function _nonIterableSpread() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArray(iter) { if (Symbol.iterator in Object(iter) || Object.prototype.toString.call(iter) === "[object Arguments]") return Array.from(iter); }

function _arrayWithoutHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { for (var i = 0, arr2 = new Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) { arr2[i] = arr[i]; } return arr2; } }

function getHiddenHTML(el) {
      return _toArray(el.childNodes).reduce(function(txt, node){
         //results
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é [sintaxe spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) e é uma maneira simples de converter algo iterável numa array. Quando se usa `querySelectorAll` por exemplo, retorna algo semelhante a um array mas que não é um array de verdade. Ou seja, é iterável no sentido em que se pode usar um loop `for` e tem o método `forEach` **mas** não tem outros métodos de array como o `reduce`.

Assim com esse sintaxe é possível "converter" numa array genuína e com todos os métodos que uma array tem.

A razão do polyfill ser tão complexo é porque há tipos diferentes de "iteráveis" e o que se pretende é converter numa array.